# How to use this date format?

Tags: python, datetime

I need to check if a date is more than a month ago.

I'm using `datetime.now()` as my starting time. The server I need to compare it to gives me a date object that looks like this `2020-03-10T09:24:27.000000Z`.

I honestly have no idea what format this is or how to parse it and check if its more than a month ago.
Anyone know this format?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: Looks like ISO 8601

Comment: If `now()` is returning that date time, you've got bigger problems...

Comment: @ScottHunter, spot on!

Comment: It doesn't, it's the server that gives me a time format like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server date is in ISO-8601 format. (year-month-dayThour:minute:second.timezone_offsetZ)

You can use the [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) package to handle it.

```
from dateutil import parser
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from dateutil import tz
```

1. To parse the server date:

```
server_date = parser.isoparse("2020-03-10T09:24:27.000000Z") # 2020-03-10 09:24:27+00:00
```

2. To calculate the difference:

```
# Timezone is needed for comparison
now = datetime.now(tz.UTC)                  # 2021-04-11 22:20:41.949821+00:00
a_month_ago = now - relativedelta(months=1) # 2021-03-11 22:20:41.949821+00:00

if server_date < a_month_ago:
  print("More than a month ago.")
```